# SIC Extension by Dun & Bradstreet?

Tags: companies, classification, industry

Dun & Bradstreet (DnB) company data uses US SIC for company classification (although that's obsoleted by NAICS). SIC is available in many places, [even as RDF](http://linkedmodel.org/vocab/industry-codes/VOCAB_sic.ttl).

However, D&B have also elaborated a SIC extension (adding 4 digits to the original 4). Does anyone know if it's available somewhere? Given it's only nomenclature data I hope it won't need a commercial license, but I've heard DnB even license the use of the DUNS number...

---

Thanks for the Padukah dataset! However, I can't figure out what coding system it uses. Eg Row 14 has these codes:

- 75204 Pet Washing & Grooming
- 29103 Reptiles
- 599930    Pet Shops

Can you relate it to either:

- SIC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Industrial_Classification#List_of_codes
- NAICS:
  https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/sssd/naics/naicsrch?chart=2017

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/thomaspepperz/list-of-businesses) of businesses from Paducah, KY, which include a SIC designation.

[image]

I'm not exactly sure what's going on with these industry codes. I looked into it briefly and since it's a six-digit code I'm wondering if it's not reflecting the NAICS 2017 revision or some other weird industry code. I didn't name the columns so I'm not sure what the history of it is. I used the dataset for other purposes whenever I originally obtained it. If you do happen to be able to verify what exactly the codes are indicating let me know.

[image: NAICS 2017 revision]

Comment: Thanks! But Can you relate it to either SIC or NAICS? See extra question above

Comment: The attached screenshot (attached to my original answer) is what that portion of data looks like. I'm sure there is a way to take a SIC number code and "translate" it into the most similar NAICS. There may be a script online or a resource that lists which SIC counts as a specific NAICS category such that many SIC may correspond to one NAICS et cetera. I have much, much more data available like that connected to the link provided, but instead of only for Paducah, KY it's for the entire US.

Comment: The above are neither SIC nor NAICS codes, that's my point. Check the 3 codes I've picked against SIC and NAICS, and you'll see. Calling a field "SIC" doesn't make it so ;-)

Comment: I think they may be the 2017 revised NAICS codes now that I look at it (I didn't label the columns and never used the data for the industry codes). I'm attaching a screen shot or two of what I think they may actually be.

Answer (score 1):

I found it here: https://www.dnb.com/utility-pages/dnb-demographic-firmographic-code-tables.html:

https://www.dnb.com/content/dam/english/dnb-solutions/sales-and-marketing/sic_8_digit_codes.xls

There are 2,4,6,8-digit SIC, Local Activity Type, and NAICS.